# Emberjs: How to get a single object from find() (findAll)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building a e-commerce site and have the shopping cart as a model accessible by the web service /api/cart/. Using the RESTAdapter, I'd like to simply call `App.Cart.find()` and always return 1 object, not an array. The cart doesn't have an ID, so calling `App.Cart.find(1)` would be wrong -- plus that would create a bad web service call: /api/cart/1.

Do I need to extend the RESTAdapter or Model to make find() on App.Cart always return an object instead of a list?

Answer (score 6):

```
App.Cart.find().then(function (result) {
  return result.get('firstObject'); 
});
```

return a promise to the first object and then do something with that if thats done. Note you can use this in the model method of route to becaulse ember handles promises nicely.

I used in that model. Works perfect in the last ember version.

```
model: function(params) {
    return App.Cart.find({slug: params.slug}).then(function (obj) {
        return obj.get('firstObject');
    });
}
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than what I was trying to do for this. Thanks!

Comment: The problem I'm finding with using this in my model method of the route is that the `then()` method seems to be firing before the JSON has returned from the server and been processed. This means that calling `result.get('firstObject')` always returns 'undefined'

Comment: As further information, it seems that isLoaded is also set to true at this point too...even though it is not. (the model does indeed get loaded eventually, just after the then() method has been called.)